# Change background color of a Label based on an event XAML built application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I am building an application to detect an event and upon that event, the Label indicating that the event was triggered should change color.

I am using XAML to build the interface of my application, Giving the label initial yellow color is easy. I want it to turn green when double clicked.

```
    <!-- setting style for the identification labels -->
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="StatusLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>



                <Label Name="L1" Margin="10,50,10,0" Content="TEST A" Width="100" Height="60"
                       Style="{StaticResource StatusLabelStyle}" MouseDoubleClick="L1_MouseDoubleClick" />
```

I tried doing it through the code behind file but failed repeatedly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809951/wpf-background-change-of-border-onmousedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Storyboard` and `Animations` for that:

```
<Label.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.MouseDoubleClick">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation  To="Green" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0.0.1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger> 
</Label.Triggers>
```